# How to create a class with TextField constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart

The class below consists of an AppBar but I want to use Text field in place of it, I don't know how to create a class constructor with Text Field and use it. I am just following the example of Appbar but it is limited to one input and I want multiple Text fields in my app.

```
class CustomLocation extends StatefulWidget {
  //final TextField textField;
  final AppBar? appBarPicker;
  final Widget? topWidgetPicker;
  final Widget? bottomWidgetPicker;
 

  CustomLocation({
    //this.textField,
    required this.controller,
    this.appBarPicker,
    this.bottomWidgetPicker,
    this.topWidgetPicker,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

   }

  @override
  _CustomLocationState createState() => _CustomLocationState();
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Builder(
      builder: (ctx) {
        return Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          appBar: widget.appBarPicker,
          //use TextField widget here to call it in another class
          //TextField : widget.textField ?
          body: Stack(
            children: [
             
              ),
            ],
           
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Create another dart file named MyTextField.dart, declare your class in it, like MyTextField which extends StatefulWidget and returns TextField like this

```
class MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyTextFieldState createState() => _MyTextFieldState();
}

class _MyTextFieldState extends State<MyTextField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      // TextField Properties you want
    );
  }
}
```

now Mention it anywhere you want to create this TextField like

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: MyTextField(), //your custom TextField 
    );
  }
}
```

You have to import that MyTextField.dart file wherever you want to use your custom textfield. you can pass value like length of characters allowed, border, error, hint, counter text and more properties using MyTextField class constructor.
It will be easy to make changes by modifying only one file.